# pandas indexing in multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i do have an excel file:

```
<>   1    2    3
A
B
C
```

with my data in each cell.

in another sheet i do have my description:

```
    name    pH    salt    id
A1    sample    8.5    50    1
A2    sample    8.5    50    1
A3    sample    8.5    50    2
B1    sample    7.5    50    2
```

reading the data and the labels:

```
d = pd.read_excel(data_name,'280', index_col = 0)
d_label =pd.read_excel(data_name,'label', index_col = 0)
```

creating a list from the data:

```
data = list(chain.from_iterable(d.values.tolist()))
```

making a multiindex:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuple(d_label.values), names=d_label.columns)
```

when I created a series:

```
s = pd.Series(data, index = index)
```

I can now index the series as usual. E.g.

```
s['some_name']
```

But if i do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = index)
```

and:

```
df['some_name']
```

i get an error:

```
'no item named some_name'
```

What did I wrong ?

Comment: You leave me extremely confused. "Series containing index": Either you're doing something weird, or you describe it weirdly - or perhaps its just me. Please state the shape of your data and what you're exactly trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the basic indexing documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#basics

When indexing a Series, `s['some_name']` will access the *row* with label `some_name`.
While when indexing a DataFrame, `df['some_name']` will access the *column* (and not row index) with label `some_name`. You can do `df.loc['some_name']` to access a row.